# Delete a line on a form, ODBC delete on a linked table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have a form that is linked to an ODBC (MS SQLServer), that is displaying a result of a VIEW.

When I try to delete a record, I invoke a function at VBA level.

```
Form_BeforeDelConfirm(Cancel As Integer, Response As Integer){
     If (IsNull(Text104.value) = False) Then
         Dim deleteLabel As DAO.QueryDef
         Set deleteLabel = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
         deleteLabel.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("KontrollWerte").Connect
         If (InStr(QuerySave, "KontrollWerteVIEW") <> 0) Then
             deleteLabel.sql = "delete from KontrollWerte_Label where Kontrolle_Label_ID = " & Text104.value
         End If
         Close
    End If 
}
```

Error shown:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server] View or function 'dbo.KontrollwerteVIEW' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables. (#4450)

This error is okay, as the view is a select with multiple tables.

It seems the function is not called, and the "default" delete function of the MS Access is being called. I there is a way to not call the default delete and instead execute my sql statement inside of the `Form_BeforeDelConfirm` function?

I tried to change when the call of function is called.

Comment: I don't know access but aren't you supposed to set Cancel variable so it doesn't delete?

Comment: Is this C++ or C#? Add appropriate language tag. Use `Cancel = True` to abort the Delete action.

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211249(v=office.11)

Comment: @June7 this is VBA, sorry to miss it.

Comment: Never seen use of {} in VBA. Does this compile?

Comment: If this is a linked view, then can you in access simple open that view? Can you edit, can you delete? TEST the view first - long before you try any code.  A view by default is read only, but you can make them read/write/delete, but try this 10 second test. If you can't from the access UI and a simple click on and open of that linked view, then don't bother trying to do as such in code - you have the same issue. You have delete that linked view, and re-link. And it will prompt you for a PK id.

Comment: @June7 Yes, this is compiling properly, and do what it should, the problem is not the procedure

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I can open the view on Access, but not able to delete, edit. I know that is not possible, so I create this function to handle this deletion/edit, and this is doing what I want, but after this is done Access calls the default procedure for deletion and the error is shown.

Comment: As I stated, if you code attempts to use the view, then that view like any other linked table must be read/write. However, if you delete the view, and add the view (as a linked table) again from access, then you ARE prompted to select a PK column, and when you do that, then yes, the view can be read/write.  So, yes, this is possible, and often done. The ONLY requirement here is that the view can be updated. (so, you can in sql manager right click on the view and choose the edit 200 rows (or whatever the message says), and again try/see/test/check if the view allows updates.

Comment: See my answer here - I point out the process of when linking a table, you MUST correctly answer the prompts when linking to a sql server view. If you correctly answer the prompt as per my screen shot in answer, then the view will become read/write/updateable like any other linked table to sql server. This is common, allowed, and is supported from ms-access.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that the view allows updates.

When you link a table, and it is a view?

The during the creating of the table link, then you will see this prompt:

First, we select the "view" when linking that "view/table"

[image]

and note I also checked the Save password option.

Then next we get/see this:

[image]

DO NOT skip the above prompt. If you don't select the PK column for that view, then it will be read only.

FYI:

The above prompt to save password, and the above prompt to select the PK when linking to that view?

It DOES NOT appear on re-link, ONLY when adding a new link!!!!

So, that's why I stated to delete the link to sql server (not just re-link and not just re-fresh table link, but Adding for first time are the key instructions here).

So, yes, views are and can be up-datable, but you MUST answer the above prompt during the linking process in Access, or the result is a read-only table.